# OAuth Class not found, Magento cpanel in php file

Tags: php, magento, oauth, cpanel

I have already installed php extension for oauth and added it into the php.ini file.Although when i tried to access the OAuth it gives me fatal error as OAuth class not found. 
I have added line like extension=oauth.so in php.ini file.

Error Log

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /home/artcon/public_html/devsource/webservice/getCategories.php on line 8

Code :

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://yourhost/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://yourhost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://yourhost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Please help

Comment: Add sample code and error logs pls

Comment: @MateenMomin i have edited the post. Look at that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the OAuthClass is not found which means a php class that is required by you php scripts is not found.

What you did in php.ini is to enable php OAuth extension. Even if the extension is enabled if you do use a php class in a php script and that class is not defined anytwhere you might get a php fatal error.

Did you restart your webserver (apache/nginx) after adding that line in php.ini? If you have just added it without restart, the changes are not in effect. Use a service httpd restart (centos) or service apache2 restart (ubuntu/debian) or a service nginx restart if you use nginx and see how it plays.